# Удаление символов строки до определенного символа

Tags: java, строки

Есть `String city = Asia/Barnaul`, как ей присвоить значение `Barnaul`? т.е. удалить все символы до "/".

Comment: `s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+1);`

Comment: Добавьте это как ответ, помечу как нужное решение, чтобы другие смогли найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение в одну строку и работоспособное даже если отсутствует символ `/`

```
s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. В Яве строки неизменяемые.

Присвоить нужное значение другой строке можно так

```
String city = "Asia/Barnaul";
String[] parts = city.split("/");
String part2 = parts[1];
```